# How to apply LIKE in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to filter out results based on an input string, and I need to use SQL `LIKE` operation for that and not a normal comparison. Couldn't find the solution online(probably didn't use the correct search words) :

```
return _context.Cities.Where(t => t.Name == cityName);
```

And I need it to do `WHERE t.name LIKE '%CityName%'` . How do I simulate it here ?

Comment: Just in case you are using EF Core 2.0+, you could also use [EF.Functions.Like()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/) if `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` and `Contains` are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

_context.Cities.Where(t=> t.Name.Contains(cityName));